# Recurring components in JSPs and Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, components

I am building a Webapp with Spring MVC and on many different pages i would like to include something like a "smart" component. For example a box that shows various objects from my database. So it needs to be able to access my service layer somehow, because I do not want to pass any object each time I use this component.

I thought about using a tag, but I don't want to create the needed objects in the controller and pass it to the tag everytime... Also I do not want to do some dirty scriptlets that load the needed services from the context.

Is there any way to do this nicely?

Comment: Did you consider placiing the "smart" component in either session or application scope?

Comment: I was not thinking about scopes yet. Just a component that is able to get the data it needs from the service layer or a controller or whatever by itself without having to give it the data. I'd like to be able place it on any JSP without caring how it gets its data. Maybe component is the wrong word for that.

Answer (score 0):

How about using ajax? You can invoke with ajax the needed controller method and this method will provide the needed object. You won't need to send that information in every response, because ajax will get it.

Comment: sure that would work and it's easy to use once it's set up. However it is also another roundtrip I'd like to avoid.